# RoR 3.1 Mysql2 Adapter + Remote DB not working when table name ends with letter "y"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql2

I am not sure whether this is a bug or if I have totally gone mad.

I have a remote database and I am able to make queries on all tables except tables which end with the letter "y"

My model:  ox_stats_country.rb

```
 class OxStatsCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :openx
    self.abstract_class = true
 end
```

The table name on the remote/legacy database is "ox_stats_country".

When I try to query something in the rails console like this: "OxStatsCountry.find(1)"

I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'openx.ox_stats_countries' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `ox_stats_countries`

As you can see, it pluralizes automatically the table name and hence is not able to find it. I have the same problem with the table name "agency". Yet with all the other tables (not ending with the letter "y") everything works fine.

Is this a bug of the mysql2 adapter? If so, where would I file such bug? Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? I am newbish to RoR and programming in general so I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks for your time... Uli

Comment: Sounds like an inflector problem, actually. Your table names should be plural, is there a reason you are making them singular?

Comment: @bricker I think that's the "legacy" part.

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, ActiveRecord looks for plural table names by default. Your table names should be plural (agencies, for example). However, you can override the table name with this in your model:

```
class Agency
  set_table_name 'agency'
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the bug question, but I know you can manually set the table name of a model with `set_table_name "ox_stats_country"`

From the api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-set_table_name